# Combine two or more functions

Tags: jquery, function, var

I have 10 images each with a class 1-10 how can i make the function work for every class? Works fine with class="1".  Just not sure how to add them together?

```
<body>
<div>
    <img src="img/13-01_basic_hover.jpg" class="1" width="220" height="184" title="huge, gigantic">
    <img src="img/13-01_basic_hover.jpg" class="2" width="220" height="184" title="Number 2">
</div>
<div class="project"></div>
<script>
var title = $(".1, .2").attr("title");
$(".project").text(title);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".project").fadeTo(0,0);
    $(".1, .2").hover(
        function () {
            $(".project").stop(true).fadeTo("normal",1);
        }, 
        function () {
            $(".project").fadeTo("normal",0);
        }
    );       
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qQANX/ -> I just replaced my code there..

Answer (score 2):

Just add them as a comma seperated value,

```
$(".1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, .10").hover(
  function () {
    $(".project")
        .text(this.title)
        .stop(true).fadeTo("normal",1);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".project").fadeTo("normal",0);
  }
);
```

Or add another class to those elements and group them and then you can,

```
$(".grouped").hover(
  function () {
     $(".project")
        .text(this.title)
        .stop(true).fadeTo("normal",1);
  }, 
  function () {
   $(".project").fadeTo("normal",0);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this. But when i hover over my second image i get the title from image one?

Comment: @ScottPedder Thats because you have the title set outside.. Check my edited code.

Comment: Thanks but same story? i would like to keep an separate class name for each image?

Comment: @ScottPedder Even still the first approach should work for you.. however you can have multiple classes as class="1 grouped".

Comment: I tried the first approach and nothing seems to happen at all? i.e the .project should be faded out to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Class names starting with numbers are invalid. You should change this.

Class names are usually used to select groups of items anyway. Just add a second class name for all your items and use that instead of `.1`.

Comment: Thankyou, but still displaying image ones title when i hover over image 2?